# Windows 10 reinstallation bootloop?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I recently had to re-install Windows because of some stubborn malware. I used a legitimate Windows 10 installer and set it to erase all personal files and data.

After the install finished, I am greeted with the "Hi there" screen asking for locale info. I'll enter the fields and proceed to the advanced or express install page. I used the advanced page to opt-out of Microsoft telemetry and proceeded. I was brought *back* to the "Hi there" screen.

So I tried again with the express install. After finishing I was met yet again with the "Hi there" screen.

Is Windows stuck in some sort of boot loop? I can't get past this step in the installation. I don't believe I installed Windows improperly, please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I should add that I installed Windows from an ISO stored on a portable backup hard drive.

Comment: Erase the drive before doing a clean install.

Comment: Even if I was willing to do so, there isn't anything else I can do on the computer. It's stuck in an infinite loop of the Windows 10 inital setup.

Comment: Sure there is but is a waste of time.

Comment: How so? Could I attempt to boot from the external hard drive?

Comment: Make a W10 install CD or usb, wipe the drive using DBAN, then start the install from CD or usb....https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-erase-a-hard-drive-using-dban-2619148